# How to filter multiple values in Datatables?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a project [Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/VZizdhY8RS9Eqp9JyOio?p=preview) which i need to filter by range of dates.

I don't know how to add the .search() method a second parameter...

I want to do something like

```
           table.column(8).search($('#filter_start_date').val() 
            + $('this').val() + ')', true).draw();
```

I've tried this :

```
        var datepickersOpt = {
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            minDate   : null
        }

        var dates = [];
        $("#filter_start_date").datepicker($.extend({

        },datepickersOpt));

        $("#filter_end_date").datepicker($.extend({
            onSelect: function() {

               dates.push('(?=.*' + $('#filter_start_date').val() + ')'); // 
               not sure about this regex

               dates.push('(?=.*' + $(this).val() + ')');

               table.column(8).search(dates.join('|'), true, false, 
              true).draw();

            }
        },datepickersOpt));
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it [Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/VZizdhY8RS9Eqp9JyOio?p=preview)

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
        var min = new Date($('#filter_start_date').val());
        var max = new Date($('#filter_end_date').val());
        var date_var =   new Date(data[4]); // use data for the age column

        if ( ( isNaN( min ) && isNaN( max ) ) || ( isNaN( min ) && date_var <= max ) ||
        ( min <= date_var   && isNaN( max ) ) || ( min <= date_var && date_var <= max ) ) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
);
```